# Restrict users from viewing Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, restrictions

Is there a way in AWS to restrict other users from viewing a specific Lambda function? It seems like currently, if anyone creates a function it will allow everyone else to view them. Is there a way to essentially make them private?

Comment: @MarkoMackic what are you talking about? The question makes perfect sense. https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/

Comment: Ok :) Thanks for informing me :) I'll delete my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Lambda API permissions in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-api-permissions-ref.html) then you will see that you can not restrict Lambda ListFunctions API based on resource. And you can not specify conditions also when listing.

| Action | Resource | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GetAccountSettings,**ListFunctions**,ListTags,TagResource,UntagResource | * | None |

But you can enhance security with checking this AWS Blog regarding granular access to Lambda functions
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/granular-access-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to restrict `lambda:ListFunctions` to only list some of the functions. However it is possible to deny a user access to a specific function by assigning him an IAM like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1461787276585",
      "Action": [
          "lambda:ListVersionsByFunction",
          "lambda:ListAliases",
          "lambda:GetFunction",
          "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
          "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
          "lambda:GetPolicy"
      ],
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "<your-function-arn>"
    }
  ]
}
```